# Reading content of non-mounted filesystems

Tags: grub

I want to read the content of not mounted filesystems.

This works fine with `grub-fstest /dev/sdba1 ls /`.

But this does not work, if the partition is mounted:

```
 grub-fstest /dev/sdba1 ls /
```

> grub-fstest: error: `loopback' command fails: can't open` (null)': No such file or directory.

Is there way to handle both cases it once?

(I know that I could write a wrapper, but maybe there is a way to do it with one command line)

Comment: The only way I know of to read data from an *un-mounted* file system is `dd`.